# Juniper MX with MS-MIC and ipsec performance

Tags: juniper, ipsec, srx

I've set up the gre over ipsec tunnel between SRX650 and MX5 (MS-MIC onboard). While SRX is able to serve ipsec tunnels traffic at about 100-200 Mbit/sec to other SRXes, I can get only about 1.5 Mbit/sec on SRX-MX link. I've played with MTU/MSS settings to ensure the proper fragmentation... but surprisingly this has zero influence on the speed, while I can observe that for instance 4k packets get fragmented properly. I've also tested the speed between same endpoints without ipsec (they have also public IPs, that are routed through the same exit points) - I get FTP transfer speed at about 100 Mbit/sec.

Is there some performance tweak that I'm unaware of ?

**Update:** revamped the configuration to get rid off the GRE intermediate incapsulation. Unfortunately, ipsec VPN speed still stays around 1.5 MBit/sec.

`show chassis hardware`:

```
emz@LDN-MX5> show chassis hardware 
Hardware inventory:
Item             Version  Part number  Serial number     Description
Chassis                                XXXXX             MX5-T
Midplane         REV 10   711-038215   XXXXXXXX          MX5-T
PEM 0            Rev 05   740-028288   XI00424           AC Power Entry Module
PEM 1            Rev 05   740-028288   XI00409           AC Power Entry Module
Routing Engine            BUILTIN      BUILTIN           Routing Engine
TFEB 0                    BUILTIN      BUILTIN           Forwarding Engine Processor
  QXM 0          REV 06   711-028408   XXXXXXXXX         MPC QXM
FPC 0                     BUILTIN      BUILTIN           MPC BUILTIN
  MIC 0                   BUILTIN      BUILTIN           4x 10GE XFP
    PIC 0                 BUILTIN      BUILTIN           4x 10GE XFP
  MIC 1          REV 02   750-061622   XXXXXXXX          MS-MIC-16G
    PIC 2                 BUILTIN      BUILTIN           MS-MIC-16G
FPC 1                     BUILTIN      BUILTIN           MPC BUILTIN
  MIC 0          REV 30   750-028392   XXXXXXXX          3D 20x 1GE(LAN) SFP
    PIC 0                 BUILTIN      BUILTIN           10x 1GE(LAN) SFP
      Xcvr 0     REV 02   740-013111   B302483           SFP-T
      Xcvr 1     REV 02   740-013111   B302729           SFP-T
      Xcvr 2     REV 02   740-013111   F172228           SFP-T
    PIC 1                 BUILTIN      BUILTIN           10x 1GE(LAN) SFP
      Xcvr 0     REV 02   740-013111   B261212           SFP-T
      Xcvr 1     REV 02   740-013111   F380617           SFP-T
      Xcvr 2     REV 02   740-013111   F150924           SFP-T
      Xcvr 3     REV 02   740-013111   B304909           SFP-T
Fan Tray                                                 Fan Tra
```

configuration, important pieces:

```
chassis {
    fpc 0 {
        pic 0 {
            tunnel-services {
                bandwidth 1g;
            }
            inline-services {
                bandwidth 1g;
            }
        }
        pic 2 {
            adaptive-services {
                service-package layer-3;
            }
        }
    }
    alarm {
        management-ethernet {
            link-down ignore;
        }
    }
}
services {
    service-set nat-lan {
        nat-rules default;
        interface-service {
            service-interface ms-0/2/0;
        }                               
    }
    service-set tcp-mss {
        tcp-mss 1343;
        service-set-options {
            enable-asymmetric-traffic-processing;
        }
        stateful-firewall-rules permit-all;
        interface-service {
            service-interface ms-0/2/0.3;
        }
    }
    service-set ipsec-srx-perm {
        next-hop-service {
            inside-service-interface ms-0/2/0.4;
            outside-service-interface ms-0/2/0.5;
        }
        ipsec-vpn-options {
            local-gateway 93.179.66.1;
        }
        ipsec-vpn-rules srx-perm;
    }
    ipsec-vpn {
        rule ipsec {
            term 1 {
                from {
                    source-address {
                        172.16.6.1/32;
                    }
                    destination-address {
                        172.16.6.0/32;
                    }
                }
                then {
                    remote-gateway 91.196.139.1;
                    dynamic {
                        ike-policy ike-policy;
                        ipsec-policy ipsec-policy;
                    }
                    initiate-dead-peer-detection;
                }
            }
            match-direction input;      
        }
        rule srx-perm {
            term default {
                from {
                    ipsec-inside-interface ms-0/2/0.4;
                }
                then {
                    remote-gateway 91.196.139.1;
                    dynamic {
                        ike-policy ike-policy;
                        ipsec-policy ipsec-policy;
                    }
                    copy-dont-fragment-bit;
                    initiate-dead-peer-detection;
                    dead-peer-detection {
                        interval 10;
                        threshold 5;
                    }
                }
            }
            match-direction input;
        }
        ipsec {
            proposal ipsec-proposal {
                protocol esp;
                authentication-algorithm hmac-sha1-96;
                encryption-algorithm aes-128-cbc;
            }
            policy ipsec-policy {
                perfect-forward-secrecy {
                    keys group2;
                }
                proposals ipsec-proposal;
            }
        }
        ike {
            proposal ike-proposal {
                authentication-method pre-shared-keys;
                dh-group group19;
                authentication-algorithm sha-256;
                encryption-algorithm aes-128-cbc;
                lifetime-seconds 14400; 
            }
            policy ike-policy {
                proposals ike-proposal;
                local-id ipv4_addr 93.179.66.1;
                pre-shared-key ascii-text "$9$oQZiqmPQz3/24F/CuIRhSrKX-wsgoJDlKx-VboaGDiHqf0OR"; ## SECRET-DATA
            }
        }
        establish-tunnels immediately;
    }
    stateful-firewall {
        rule permit-all {
            match-direction input-output;
            term accept {
                then {
                    accept;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    nat {
        pool pool-default {
            address 93.179.66.3/32;
            port {
                automatic;
            }
        }
        rule default {
            match-direction input;
            term no-nat {
                from {
                    destination-address {
                        10.0.0.0/8;
                        192.168.0.0/16;
                        172.16.0.0/12;
                    }
                }
                then {
                    no-translation;
                }
            }
            term default {
                from {                  
                    source-address {
                        10.10.116.0/24;
                        10.10.102.0/23;
                    }
                }
                then {
                    translated {
                        source-pool pool-default;
                        translation-type {
                            napt-44;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
interfaces {
    ms-0/2/0 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet;
        }
        unit 1 {
            family inet;
            service-domain inside;
        }
        unit 2 {
            family inet;
            service-domain outside;
        }
        unit 3 {
            description "TCP MSS Modification";
            family inet;
            family inet6;
        }
        unit 4 {
            description "SRX, Perm";    
            family inet {
                mtu 1383;
                service {
                    input {
                        service-set tcp-mss service-filter mss-filter;
                    }
                    output {
                        service-set tcp-mss service-filter mss-filter;
                    }
                }
                address 10.200.200.17/32 {
                    destination 10.200.200.16;
                }
            }
            family inet6;
            service-domain inside;
        }
        unit 5 {
            family inet;
            family inet6;
            service-domain outside;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe your MX5 handles IPSEC in CPU? In that case I would check options of offloading IPSEC processing to hardware.

Comment: Can you post your configuration and output of "show chassis hardware"?

Comment: Sure, added to the post.

Comment: @manishma I'm not familiar with explicit ipsec offloading to the hardware. On SRX there was none; did not find any mentions of this related to the MX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I discovered that MX ipsec configuration is absolutely correct, and there's no hidden tweaks/no directive that explicitly accelerate ipsec processing. The used bandwidth inside UK ipsec VPN links is about ***380 Mbit/sec***, which is close to contracted SLA.

Seems like I hit some ipsec policer on the transit from continental Europe to UK. Playing with BGP announces gives me bandwidth boost from 1.5 Mbit/sec to ***40 Mbit/sec*** when transmitting/receiving from continental Europe via VPN.